# Having problems when implementing a many-to-many relationship in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, many-to-many, mongoid

I'm building a Rails app and I'm having a little bit of trouble when implementing a Team and User many to many relationship, that way an User can be part of multiple teams and a team obviously can have multiple users. Those are my current models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document   
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams, :class_name => 'Team', :inverse_of => :member
end

class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :teams
end
```

The problem I have is that when I test this on the Rails console, it just doesn't makes sense:

```
2.0.0-p0 :002 > u = User.first
 => #<User _id: 519c692e38508ce07e000001, team_ids: ["519c6f1338508c9431000001"]>
2.0.0-p0 :005 > t = u.teams.new
 => #<Team _id: 519c6fcd38508c08e0000001, member_ids: ["519c692e38508ce07e000001"]>
2.0.0-p0 :006 > u.teams
 => [#<Team _id: 519c6fcd38508c08e0000001, member_ids: ["519c692e38508ce07e000001"]>]
2.0.0-p0 :008 > t.members
 => []
```

Why doesn't the team members relationship shows me the user, but the array has its ID? It should contain the user object, as I used `u.teams.new`. I tried different things, but all yielding a similar result (such as the user not listing any teams, but having its ID on the array). How can I fix this? Thanks!

PD: I'm running edge Mongoid (from git's master), Rails (4.0.0.rc1) and Ruby (2.0.0-p0)

Comment: Shouldnt it be :inverse_of => :members in User model instead of member?

Comment: Whoops didn't notice. Although it's still the same problem, it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Mongoid fault actually. This was because my dev VM had MongoDB 1.4 installed (don't ask why, I have no idea). Upgraded to the latest version and now it's perfect!